# Unity2d why I don't see game tab, it's blue only

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I have sought for the answer for so long (15 minutes :D), please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue you are seeing is the default color for the camera when you set The clear flags variable to SolidColor, so your camera is probably okay..

Its most likely behind your sprites. Check the camera's Z position, and place it front of them, unity's 2D is actually 3D, you can switch to 3D mode and see what's ur camera's position in the z axis.

edit: Just switch to 3D mode and see it, your camera is a child GameObject, so the coordinates are in local Space,it'll be hard to tell wether or not the camera is in front of anything.